# Angular @input decorator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello there learning angular and came across the @input decorators in angular. After researching the topic I still have some difficulty wrapping my head around this concept.

### Code:

*app.component.html:*

```
<app-tutorials [bar]="foo"></app-tutorials>
```

*app.component.ts:*

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  foo = {
    name: 'willem',
  }
}
```

*tutorial.component.html:*

```
<p>{{bar.name}}</p>
```

*tutorial.component.ts:*

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tutorials',
  templateUrl: './tutorials.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tutorials.component.css']
})
export class TutorialsComponent{
  @Input() bar
}
```

### Question:

Is my current understanding below correct? Also if you have additional information in your answer of things I have overlooked or might be helpful for this topic I would greatly appreciate it.

- `@input`is used to transfer data only from parent components to child components.
- We use property binding: `<app-tutorials [bar]="foo"></app-tutorials>` to pass the data of `foo` in the app-tutorials component.
- We then can use this data in the tutorials.component.ts file by using `@input`.
- With string interpolation we can bind a variable only from its own ts file but since we now have used `@input` we can use it also in this HTML template.

Comment: you are correct1 what answer you need

Comment: Thanks just wanted to know if I was correct cause I read like 3 articles on this and still wasn't sure. If you have anything usefull to add you can make an answer out of this if you want.